# Getting Ign with local repository Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, localrepository

I've made local repo with apt-mirror (this one https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror). So, I've loaded both amd64 and i386 and my mirror.list looks like

```
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy            main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security   main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates    main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports  main restricted universe multiverse

deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy            main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security   main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates    main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports  main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

On my PC **without Internet connection** sources.list set to read folders from external USB HDD drive in way like^

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/media/$username$/$disk_name$/repo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
....
```

After typing sudo apt-get update I have something like that:

```
Get 1: blah-blah-blah
Ign 1: blah-blah-blah
and etc etc etc
```

Also tried with apache2 server got the same. What's wrong am I do?

P.S. Googled a couple of days, but don't find anything that could help

Comment: What is the problem? It is normal.

Comment: The problem is that I can't install and upgrade anything, cause 'Package smth not found'

Also, after apt-get update I have error in the end: ```E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead```

Answer (score 1):

So, solved my problem using docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gregewing/apt-mirror). But changed apt-mirror in this image to [this one](https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror)